# Rails/Bootstrap alert close button style is broken

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to render Bootstrap alerts for the flash messages. I wanted to get the styling right so I just copied the code from [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#alerts-dismissible) into my layout page like so:

```
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
  <strong>Warning!</strong> Better check yourself, you're not looking too good.
</div>

<%= yield %>
```

I added to `application.css.scss`

```
@import "twitter/bootstrap/alerts";
```

and `application.js`

```
//= require jquery
//= require twitter/bootstrap
```

The close button works fine, but as you can see the styling has the button on the left hand side in some weird style where in the example it's on the right hand side and much neater. I would rather not have to do the CSS by hand to get it to look like it's supposed to. Is there something I am missing?

Thanks in advance.

[image: broken close button]

**EDIT**

The gem that is being used here [has been deprecated](https://github.com/yabawock/bootstrap-sass-rails). Which makes this tricky. I have looked for any custom styling the only overrides are

```
$container-sm: 710px;
$container-md: 930px;
```

Comment: Could you please provide the example as well as any custom css you've written that relates to the button?

Comment: hey @Jeff I have updated the repo with the gem we are using to bring in bootstrap and then what we are overriding within the css

Comment: It's possible that the old gem is using an older version of bootstrap than the one you are using as documentation. Maybe try updating to the gem they recommend here https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass first?

Comment: Hey @Jeff, that is right. I went and updated the Gem to the latest version and it's working out of the box. Thanks for all your help!